# How do I changed field name reference to specific text?

Tags: apex, email, class

Right now, auto emails are sending out with "Case Resolution" in the email because the field name is being pulled in. I don't want to change the field name. I want to replace the field reference with the text "Case Update". Can anyone help with that? Here is a piece of the code that seems to be pulling in the field name. Thank you!

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    gen.WriteStartObject();
    gen.WriteFieldName('to');
    gen.WriteStartArray();

    for(Case c : newCaseList){
        gen.WriteString(c.Email__c);
    }

    gen.WriteEndArray();

    gen.WriteFieldName('sub');          
    gen.WriteStartObject();
    gen.WriteFieldName('-Name-');
    gen.WriteStartArray();

    for(Case c : newCaseList){
       gen.WriteString(c.Calculated_Contact_Name__c);
    }   

    gen.WriteEndArray();

    gen.WriteFieldName('-CaseId-');
    gen.WriteStartArray();

    for(Case c : newCaseList){
        gen.WriteString(c.CaseNumber);
    }

    gen.WriteEndArray();

    gen.WriteFieldName('-CaseThreadId-');
    gen.WriteStartArray();

    for(Case c : newCaseList){
        gen.WriteString(c.Case_Thread_ID__c);
    }   

    gen.WriteEndArray();  

    gen.WriteFieldName('-FromEmail-');
    gen.WriteStartArray();

    for(Case c : newCaseList){
        gen.WriteString(c.From_Email_LOB__c);
    }   

    gen.WriteEndArray();

    gen.WriteFieldName('-CaseCreator-');
    gen.WriteStartArray();

    for(Case c : newCaseList){
        gen.WriteString(c.Creator_Name__c);
    }  

    gen.WriteEndArray();        
    gen.WriteEndObject();
    gen.WriteEndObject();
    gen.Close();
```

Comment: Can we get a more complete code sample? Also, I'm a bit concerned for your "gen" class. It might be an unnecessary layer of abstraction. Salesforce enforces strict governor limits and unnecessary layers of abstraction add to the CPU load which is a no-no.

Comment: Hi Toby. The apex class is nearly 400 lines long, so I am not sure which parts to show you.

Comment: I know, the code is a cluster :( That's why we're trying to simplify and eventually move away from it.

Comment: From what I can tell you are using your gen class to generate the email to be sent. That would be were most of the code we need to see is.

Comment: Oh! I edited the code in, at the top :) Thanks so much for having a look!

Comment: How are you sending the email? Are you using the salesforce email functionality or making a callout to an external system?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell after playing around with it for a while. You appear to be doing everything correctly. My money is on a data issue.

Try debugging the data before and after you write it to the JSONGenerator:

```
system.debug('Case Resolution: ' + c.Resolution);
gen.writeString(c.resolution);
system.debug(gen.getAsString);
```

If the debug before you write it is wrong, it's a data issue. If the debug after you write it is wrong, it's a bug in the SF provided JSONGenerator class. If that's the case, consider creating the data and then using JSON.serialize instead.

```
List<Object> email = new List<Object>();

Map<String, List<Object>> toField = new Map<String, List<Object>>();
toField.put('to', new List<String>());

For (Case c : newCaseList) {
    toField.get('to').add(c.Email__c);
}

email.add(toField);

system.debug(JSON.serialize(email));
```

Lastly, if both debugs are correct, the issue is 1) not included in the code provided -or- 2) exists in an external system you may be making a call to.